# Why is this an illegal start of expression?

Tags: java, netbeans

I made this method in java that replaces the vowels of a String if it contains letter 'i':

```
public static boolean esVocal(Character c) {
    boolean res = false;
    if (c == 'a' | c == 'o' | c == 'e' | c == 'u') {
        res = true;   
    }
}
```

Anyway, the error that gives me is:

```
illegal start of expression
```

And at the end, it says that the method requires a `return`.

Could the error be in the syntax?

Comment: The only error is the lack of a return value. Add `return res;` Of course, if that method is placed where it shouldn't (for example, inside another method or outside a class), you'll get other errors.

Comment: It isn't placed inside any other methods. I'll try your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

Your method signature

```
public static boolean esVocal(Character c)
```

declares the **return type** `boolean`. This means your method is supposed to **return something** of type `boolean`.

---

### Solution

If you don't want to return anything you should declare the return type as `void`:

```
public static void esVocal(Character c)
```

Or if you want to return something you need to add the corresponding statement to your method:

```
public static boolean esVocal(Character c) {
    boolean res = false;

    if (c == 'a' | c == 'o' | c == 'e' | c == 'u') {
        res = true;   
    }

    // You probably wanted to return this
    return res;
}
```

---

### Notes

Note that you can reduce your method by directly returning the resulting `boolean` like:

```
public static boolean esVocal(Character c) {
    return c == 'a' | c == 'o' | c == 'e' | c == 'u';
}
```

The operator `|` on **numbers** is **not** the **logical or**. It is a **bit-wise inclusive or operation** which makes some bit-manipulations on values like:

```
   0100 1110
or 1000 1011
   ---------
   1100 1111
```

However on `boolean` expressions, like in your case, it also performs as **logical or** (see [JLS 15.22.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)).

There is also the operator `||` which always behaves as **logical or**.

Note that there is a difference between both operators, even when using on `boolean` values. The `|` operator will always compute the whole expression, even when the resulting value already is clear. The `||` aborts evaluation if the result already is clear like in

```
true || someBoolean || someOtherBoolean
```

The `true` already makes the whole result `true` and `||` will thus not evaluate the rest of the expression whereas `|` will.

In your case however you probably want to use `||`:

```
c == 'a' || c == 'o' || c == 'e' || c == 'u'
```

For the **logical and** `&`, `&&` the difference is the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you are considering logical OR operations, it is preferred to use `||` instead of `|` operator. So, you can update the `if` condition as follows. [A nice explanation is provided in the other answer]

```
if (c=='a' || c=='o' || c=='e' || c=='u'){
    res=true;   
}
```

Also, your method signature declares the return type as boolean, so you are required to return a boolean value from the function. You can simply do the following.

```
public static boolean esVocal(Character c){
    return c=='a' || c=='o' || c=='e' || c=='u';
}
```

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect. While using `||` would be better, `|` works fine, it's just not short-circuiting.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer.